# <noscript> tag - yay or nay?

Tags: noscript

There is some important information related to the user that is stored inside TabContainer control of ajaxcontroltoolkit. However, if javascript is not enabled, the tabcontainer just disappears (instead of degrading gracefully).  So I decided to have list contents of the tabs myself all in one place one after another but inside the noscript tag.  Any problems you see with this?

Any alternate suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds reasonable to me.  And shame on Microsoft for not thinking towards graceful degradation!

Comment: so did the tabcontainer disappear on you too? I want to make sure I am not missing something.

Comment: I haven't tried.  Luckily, I delayed implementing ajax until jQuery was available.

Comment: But there are many other examples of asp.net stuff not degrading gracefully without javascript.  `<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(...);">` being a pretty major one.

Comment: What, it only dissappears in IE?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this is exactly the situation where the noscript tag was made for. So yes go for it.